# Oracle xmltype column, create xmlindex with include below path

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xmltype, xmlindex

I need to create an xmlindex on and xmltype column, the system is Oracle 11g.  The code I am using is:

```
CREATE INDEX "TS"."XMLINDEX_NBXML" ON "TS"."NETBOTZ" V (NBXML) INDEXTYPE IS
XDB.XMLINDEX PARAMETERS('PATH TABLE NETBOTZ_PATH_TABLE( TABLESPACE USERS) PATHS
(/variable-set/variable[@class="nbTempSensor"]/double-val )')
```

The error received is:
SQL Error

Failed to commit: ORA-29958: fatal error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine ORA-30968: invalid XPATH or NAMESPACE option for XML Index

The XML file is below.  I tried "/variable-set/variable[@class="nbTempSensor"]/double-val" as the path parameter since we used this successfully within a view to retrieve the nbTempSensor value.  Can you tell what the correct syntax is for the path?  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <variable-set timestamp="1351899921109" time="2012-11-02 16:45:21"         
now="1351899921118">
- <variable varid="nbBaseEnclosure" guid="B035DF7_nbBaseEnclosure" class="nbEnclosure" 
classpath="/nbEnclosure">
  <u32-val>2</u32-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbEncMenuIcons">
- <string-list-val>
  <string-val>menu_link_wall_unplug.gif</string-val> 
  <string-val>menu_link_wall_error.gif</string-val> 
  <string-val>menu_link_wall.gif</string-val> 
  </string-list-val>
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbProductData">
- <struct-val>
+ <struct-element fieldid="vendor">
  <string-val>NetBotz, Inc.</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="type">
  <string-val>Wall</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="model">
  <string-val>420</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="fullmodel">
  <string-val>NetBotz 420</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="submodel">
  <string-val>420 Wall</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="serial_num">
  <string-val>00:02:D3:03:5D:F7</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="manufacturer">
  <string-val>NetBotz, Inc.</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="revision">
  <string-val>A00</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="board_id">
  <string-val>0000</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="osversion">
  <string-val>V2_6_2_20071031_1658</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="appversion">
  <string-val>V2_6_2_20071031_1658</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="apcappversion">
  <string-val>apc_bw02_bw_262.bin</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="mac_addr">
  <string-val>00:02:D3:03:5D:F7</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="manuf_date">
  <utc-val>1232625600</utc-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="svc_date">
  <utc-val>1251417512</utc-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="bootversion">
  <string-val>V2_6_2_20071031_1658</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="apcaosversion">
  <string-val>apc_bw02_aos_262.bin</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
  </struct-val>
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLocationData" isclassdef="yes">
  <struct-val /> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbSerialNum">
  <string-val>00:02:D3:03:5D:F7</string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncNBCIcon">
  <string-val>wall420_all.png</string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel">
  <nls-string-val raw="NetBotz 420">NetBotz 420</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEnum" isclassdef="yes">
- <nls-string-list-val>
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Disconnected%}">Disconnected</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Error%}">Error</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Normal%}">Normal</nls-string-val> 
  </nls-string-list-val>
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbHawkEnc_0" guid="B035DF7_nbHawkEnc_0" class="nbHawkEnc" 
classpath="/nbEnclosure/nbUSBEnclosure/nbHawkEnc">
  <u32-val>2</u32-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbDockedToEncID">
  <varid-val>nbBaseEnclosure</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncMenuIcons" isclassdef="yes">
- <string-list-val>
  <string-val>menu_link_pod_unplug.gif</string-val> 
  <string-val>menu_link_pod_error.gif</string-val> 
  <string-val>menu_link_pod.gif</string-val> 
  </string-list-val>
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLocationData" isclassdef="yes">
  <struct-val /> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbSerialNum">
  <string-val>SENSOR_00:02:D3:03:5D:F7</string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncNBCIcon" isclassdef="yes">
  <string-val>sensor_pod.png</string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{|Sensor Pod%}">Sensor Pod</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEnum" isclassdef="yes">
- <nls-string-list-val>
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Disconnected%}">Disconnected</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Error%}">Error</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Normal%}">Normal</nls-string-val> 
  </nls-string-list-val>
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbEyeEnc_0" guid="B035DF7_nbEyeEnc_0" class="nbEyeEnc" 
classpath="/nbEnclosure/nbUSBEnclosure/nbEyeEnc">
  <u32-val>2</u32-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbDockedToEncID">
  <varid-val>nbBaseEnclosure</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncMenuIcons" isclassdef="yes">
- <string-list-val>
  <string-val>menu_link_camera_unplug.gif</string-val> 
  <string-val>menu_link_camera_error.gif</string-val> 
  <string-val>menu_link_camera.gif</string-val> 
  </string-list-val>
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLocationData" isclassdef="yes">
  <struct-val /> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbSerialNum">
  <string-val>CAMERA_00:02:D3:03:5D:F7</string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncNBCIcon" isclassdef="yes">
  <string-val>camera_pod.png</string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Camera|%}">Camera</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEnum" isclassdef="yes">
- <nls-string-list-val>
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Disconnected%}">Disconnected</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Error%}">Error</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Normal%}">Normal</nls-string-val> 
  </nls-string-list-val>
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbIPInterface_eth0_status" guid="B035DF7_nbIPInterface_eth0_status" 
class="nbIPInterfaceStatus" classpath="/nbIPInterfaceStatus">
- <struct-val>
- <struct-element fieldid="enable">
  <bool-val val="false" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="hostname">
  <string-val /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="ip">
  <string-val /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="subnet">
  <string-val /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="gateway">
  <string-val /> 
  </struct-element>
+ <struct-element fieldid="usedhcp">
  <bool-val val="true" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="linkisup">
  <bool-val val="false" /> 
  </struct-element>
  </struct-val>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbWirelessIPInterface_wlan0_status"     
guid="B035DF7_nbWirelessIPInterface_wlan0_status" class="nbIPInterfaceStatus" 
classpath="/nbIPInterfaceStatus">
- <struct-val>
- <struct-element fieldid="enable">
  <bool-val val="true" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="hostname">
  <string-val>thm-netbotz</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="ip">
  <string-val>10.0.1.7</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="subnet">
  <string-val>255.255.255.128</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="gateway">
  <string-val>10.0.1.8</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="usedhcp">
  <bool-val val="false" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="leapsupport">
  <bool-val val="false" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="authsupport">
  <bool-val val="true" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="linkisup">
  <bool-val val="true" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="essid">
  <string-val>Sparta</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="mode">
  <u32-val>2</u32-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="channel">
  <u32-val>6</u32-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="frequency">
  <u32-val>2437000</u32-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="bit_rate">
  <u32-val>11000000</u32-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="link_stats_percent">
  <bool-val val="true" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="link_quality">
  <u32-val>91</u32-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="link_level">
  <i32-val>39</i32-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="link_rating">
  <u32-val>3</u32-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="access_point">
  <octet-val>00259CAD7579</octet-val> 
  </struct-element>
  </struct-val>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbConfigUpdTime" guid="B035DF7_nbConfigUpdTime"     
class="nbConfigUpdTimeCls" classpath="/nbConfigUpdTimeCls">
  <utc-val>1351782846</utc-val> 
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbPeriodicHTTP" class="nbPeriodicReportHTTP"     
classpath="/nbPeriodicReport/nbPeriodicReportHTTP">
- <struct-val>
- <struct-element fieldid="enable">
  <bool-val val="true" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="url_0">
  <string-val>https://tsdevel.therascan.net/scan/main/netbotz.php</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="userid_0">
  <string-val>amcare</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="password_0">
  <password-val /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="url_1">
  <string-val>http://</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="userid_1">
  <string-val /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="password_1">
  <password-val /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="secopt">
  <u32-val>0</u32-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="schedule">
  <string-val>0 0 0 0 0 0 0</string-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="interval">
  <u32-val>900</u32-val> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="incpix">
  <bool-val val="false" /> 
  </struct-element>
- <struct-element fieldid="sensorprio">
  <i32-val>30</i32-val> 
  </struct-element>
  </struct-val>
- <metadata slotid="nbLastReportSuccessful">
  <bool-val val="true" /> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel">
  <nls-string-val raw="Periodic HTTP Report">Periodic HTTP Report</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbLinkStatus_eth0" guid="B035DF7_nbLinkStatus_eth0"     
class="nbLinkStatusSnr"     
classpath="/nbSensor/nbStateSensor/nbBoolSensor/nbLinkStatusSnr">
  <u32-val>0</u32-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbBaseEnclosure</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLocationData" isclassdef="yes">
  <struct-val /> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{|Ethernet Link Status%}">Ethernet Link Status</nls-string-
val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEnum" isclassdef="yes">
- <nls-string-list-val>
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Down%}">Down</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Up%}">Up</nls-string-val> 
  </nls-string-list-val>
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbLinkStatus_wlan0" guid="B035DF7_nbLinkStatus_wlan0"     
class="nbLinkStatusSnr"     
classpath="/nbSensor/nbStateSensor/nbBoolSensor/nbLinkStatusSnr">
  <u32-val>1</u32-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbBaseEnclosure</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLocationData" isclassdef="yes">
  <struct-val /> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{|Wireless Link Status %s|wlan0%}">Wireless Link Status 
wlan0</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEnum" isclassdef="yes">
- <nls-string-list-val>
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Down%}">Down</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Up%}">Up</nls-string-val> 
  </nls-string-list-val>
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbEyeEnc_0_CMOT" guid="B035DF7_nbEyeEnc_0_CMOT" class="nbCamMotSnr" 
classpath="/nbSensor/nbStateSensor/nbBoolSensor/nbCamMotSnr">
  <u32-val>0</u32-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbEyeEnc_0</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLocationData">
  <struct-val /> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel" isclassdef="yes">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Camera Motion%}">Camera Motion</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEnum" isclassdef="yes">
- <nls-string-list-val>
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|No Motion%}">No Motion</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Motion Detected%}">Motion Detected</nls-string-val> 
  </nls-string-list-val>
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbEyeEnc_0_DOOR" guid="B035DF7_nbEyeEnc_0_DOOR" 
class="nbDoorSensor" classpath="/nbSensor/nbStateSensor/nbBoolSensor/nbDoorSensor">
  <u32-val isnull="yes" /> 
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbEyeEnc_0</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLocationData">
  <struct-val /> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel" isclassdef="yes">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Door Switch%}">Door Switch</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEnum" isclassdef="yes">
- <nls-string-list-val>
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Open%}">Open</nls-string-val> 
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Closed%}">Closed</nls-string-val> 
  </nls-string-list-val>
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbHawkEnc_0_DEW" guid="B035DF7_nbHawkEnc_0_DEW"     
class="nbDewPointSensor" classpath="/nbSensor/nbNumSensor/nbDewPointSensor">
  <double-val>11.300000</double-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbUnitsID" isclassdef="yes">
  <varid-val>nbUnits_DegC</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbHawkEnc_0</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel" isclassdef="yes">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Dew Point%}">Dew Point</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbHawkEnc_0_AUDI" guid="B035DF7_nbHawkEnc_0_AUDI" 
class="nbAudioSensor" classpath="/nbSensor/nbNumSensor/nbAudioSensor">
  <double-val>2.000000</double-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbHawkEnc_0</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel" isclassdef="yes">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Audio%}">Audio</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbHawkEnc_0_AFLW" guid="B035DF7_nbHawkEnc_0_AFLW"     
class="nbAirflowSensor" classpath="/nbSensor/nbNumSensor/nbAirflowSensor">
  <double-val>22.859994</double-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbUnitsID" isclassdef="yes">
  <varid-val>nbUnits_MetersPerMinute</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbHawkEnc_0</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel" isclassdef="yes">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Air Flow%}">Air Flow</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbHawkEnc_0_HUMI" guid="B035DF7_nbHawkEnc_0_HUMI" 
class="nbHumidSensor" classpath="/nbSensor/nbNumSensor/nbHumidSensor">
  <double-val>39.000000</double-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbUnitsID" isclassdef="yes">
  <varid-val>nbUnits_PctRH</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbHawkEnc_0</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel" isclassdef="yes">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Humidity%}">Humidity</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbHawkEnc_0_TEMP" guid="B035DF7_nbHawkEnc_0_TEMP" 
class="nbTempSensor" classpath="/nbSensor/nbNumSensor/nbTempSensor">
  <double-val>26.400000</double-val> 
- <metadata slotid="nbUnitsID" isclassdef="yes">
  <varid-val>nbUnits_DegC</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbHawkEnc_0</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel" isclassdef="yes">
  <nls-string-val raw="%{nbMsg|Temperature%}">Temperature</nls-string-val> 
  </metadata>
  </variable>
- <variable varid="nbEyeEnc_0_CAMERA" guid="B035DF7_nbEyeEnc_0_CAMERA" 
class="nbEyeCamera" classpath="/nbCamera/nbEyeCamera">
- <struct-val>
- <struct-element fieldid="motion">
  <u32-val>0</u32-val> 
  </struct-element>
  </struct-val>
- <metadata slotid="nbEncID">
  <varid-val>nbEyeEnc_0</varid-val> 
  </metadata>
- <metadata slotid="nbLabel">
  <nls-string-val raw="" /> 
  </metadata>
  </variable>
  </variable-set>
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot do this. the XMLINDEX document states this is not allowed:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_indexing.htm#ADXDB4385

> The paths must reference only child and descendant axes, and they must
>   test only element and attribute nodes or their names (possibly using
>   wildcards). In particular, **the paths must not involve predicates**.

as the value you're interested in occurs once in the xml document, you can create a regular index on it. otherwise you have to index all "variable" paths.

```
SQL> create index foo on netbotz(to_number(extractvalue(nbxml,'/variable-set/variable[@class="nbTempSensor"]/double-val')));

Index created.

SQL> explain plan for select * from netbotz where to_number(extractvalue(nbxml,'/variable-set/variable[@class="nbTempSensor"]/double-val')) between 1 and 4;

Explained.

SQL> select * From table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 992868181

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |         |     1 |  2002 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| NETBOTZ |     1 |  2002 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FOO     |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, clear and concise.  We were able to create the indexes as described.